# Fox and rabbit on circular path

Tags: puzzle

Thank you for your solutions "Can fox catch rabbit" (There are five holes in a line. One of them is occupied by a rabbit. Each night, the rabbit moves to a neighboring hole, either to the left or to the right. Each morning, a fox get to inspect a hole of its choice. What strategy would ensure that the fox can eventually caught rabbit?) but I can't any idea these questions:

1)Let's have 5 holes again, but this time they should be circular instead of side by side; so the rabbit can jump from hole 1 to hole 5. Does the fox have a strategy that guarantees catching the rabbit?

2)In which configuration of n holes does the fox have a strategy that guarantees catching the rabbit?

3)Let's have 5 holes and they are lined up, but the rabbit can stay in the hole at night. Can the fox guarantee to catch the rabbit?

Comment: If the rabbit on every night has a choice of which holes to appear in, then it can always evade the fox by picking the hole that the fox does not choose. So the answers for questions 1 and 3 are obvious.

Comment: Also posted at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121543/fox-and-rabbit-on-a-circle

Comment: You should give the link to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4733682/305862)